# reading json file in a dataframe and converting it back to exact json

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a requirement, where I need to read multiple Json file present in s3 bucket, I am using below code

```
path = "s3://some-bucket/some-key/*.json"
df = spark.read.json(path)
```

Now, I have Json data in this Dataframe, but how can I convert it back to exact same Json format which was there while reading it ? I know I can convert this spark df to pandas df, but i tried all the options of pandas orient parameter, none of them giving me same exact Json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**df.write.json** will write the dataframe to json file. Please share more details on json format if below is not helpful.

```
>>> df = spark.read.json('/home/tm/json_sample.json')
>>> df.show()
+--------------------+
|            employee|
+--------------------+
|[true, sonoo, 56000]|
+--------------------+

>>> df.write.json('/home/tm/json_sample1.json')
```

Data in json_sample.json

```
{"employee":{"married":true,"name":"sonoo","salary":56000}}
```

Data in output file (part-00000-d319741f-7fb1-416a-8906-78ebfc5a1df1-c000.json)

```
{"employee":{"married":true,"name":"sonoo","salary":56000}}
```

Comment: Thanks @Chaitra ! this seems to be working , but is it possible to store it in a variable ? so that i can use that variable? i mean, i read the json file and stored the content in a variable in the exact same format as it is present in json file. ??

Comment: Yes it is possible. But if you want to store the content in variable then you will have to use 'collect' which is not recommended as its not feasible when you deal with larger dataset.

Comment: yes Chaitra, you are correct! but i was just exploring it, if we can store it. anyways thanks for your help!! just FYI when tried with collect() it returned me data as list. i tried below one which is giving me the exact same json format data. my_variable = json.loads(df.toJSON().first())

Comment: Hi @hegde  can you help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69083312/convert-nested-json-to-csv-or-table