# Convert nested JSON to CSV or table

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I know this question has been asked many times but none of the answers satisfy my requirement. I want to dynamically convert **any nested JSON** to a CSV file or Dataframe. Some sample examples are:

```
input : {"menu": {
    "header": "SVG Viewer",
    "items": [
        {"id": "Open"},
        {"id": "OpenNew", "label": "Open New"},
        null,
        {"id": "ZoomIn", "label": "Zoom In"},
        {"id": "ZoomOut", "label": "Zoom Out"},
        {"id": "OriginalView", "label": "Original View"},
        null,
        {"id": "Quality"},
        {"id": "Pause"},
        {"id": "Mute"},
        null,
        {"id": "Find", "label": "Find..."},
        {"id": "FindAgain", "label": "Find Again"},
        {"id": "Copy"},
        {"id": "CopyAgain", "label": "Copy Again"},
        {"id": "CopySVG", "label": "Copy SVG"},
        {"id": "ViewSVG", "label": "View SVG"},
        {"id": "ViewSource", "label": "View Source"},
        {"id": "SaveAs", "label": "Save As"},
        null,
        {"id": "Help"},
        {"id": "About", "label": "About Adobe CVG Viewer..."}
    ]
}}
```

Output: [image]

```
input 2 : {"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

Output 2: [image]

So far I have tried below code, which works fine but it explodes the list type data into columns, but I want it be exploded in rows.

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd


def flatten_json(y):
    out = {}

    def flatten(x, name=''):
        if type(x) is dict:
            
            for a in x:
                
                flatten(x[a], name + a + '.')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, name + str(i) + '.')
                i += 1
        else:
            
            out[str(name[:-1])] = str(x)

    flatten(y)
    return out
  
def start_explode(data):
    
  if type(data) is dict: 
    df = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(data)])
  else:
    df = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(x) for x in data])
  
  df = df.astype(str)
  return df

complex_json = {"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
df = start_explode(complex_json['menu'])
display(df)
```

It gives output like below for one the above inputs:

[image]

Comment: Please, check [ask]. What have you tried so far, what particular problem you were not able to solve on your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- standard techniques for dealing with nested json

  1. `json_normalize()`
  2. `explode()`
  3. `apply(pd.Series)`
- finally some cleanup, drop unwanted rows and replace `nan` with empty string

```
import json
js = """{"menu": {
    "header": "SVG Viewer",
    "items": [
        {"id": "Open"},
        {"id": "OpenNew", "label": "Open New"},
        null,
        {"id": "ZoomIn", "label": "Zoom In"},
        {"id": "ZoomOut", "label": "Zoom Out"},
        {"id": "OriginalView", "label": "Original View"},
        null,
        {"id": "Quality"},
        {"id": "Pause"},
        {"id": "Mute"},
        null,
        {"id": "Find", "label": "Find..."},
        {"id": "FindAgain", "label": "Find Again"},
        {"id": "Copy"},
        {"id": "CopyAgain", "label": "Copy Again"},
        {"id": "CopySVG", "label": "Copy SVG"},
        {"id": "ViewSVG", "label": "View SVG"},
        {"id": "ViewSource", "label": "View Source"},
        {"id": "SaveAs", "label": "Save As"},
        null,
        {"id": "Help"},
        {"id": "About", "label": "About Adobe CVG Viewer..."}
    ]
}}"""

df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(js)).explode("menu.items").reset_index(drop=True)
df.drop(columns=["menu.items"]).join(df["menu.items"].apply(pd.Series)).dropna(subset=["id"]).fillna("")
```

|  | menu.header | id | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SVG Viewer | Open |  |
| 1 | SVG Viewer | OpenNew | Open New |
| 3 | SVG Viewer | ZoomIn | Zoom In |
| 4 | SVG Viewer | ZoomOut | Zoom Out |
| 5 | SVG Viewer | OriginalView | Original View |
| 7 | SVG Viewer | Quality |  |
| 8 | SVG Viewer | Pause |  |
| 9 | SVG Viewer | Mute |  |
| 11 | SVG Viewer | Find | Find... |
| 12 | SVG Viewer | FindAgain | Find Again |
| 13 | SVG Viewer | Copy |  |
| 14 | SVG Viewer | CopyAgain | Copy Again |
| 15 | SVG Viewer | CopySVG | Copy SVG |
| 16 | SVG Viewer | ViewSVG | View SVG |
| 17 | SVG Viewer | ViewSource | View Source |
| 18 | SVG Viewer | SaveAs | Save As |
| 20 | SVG Viewer | Help |  |
| 21 | SVG Viewer | About | About Adobe CVG Viewer... |

#### utility function

- if you don't want to name columns, but take first list column
- identify first column that contains lists
- `explode()` and `apply(pd.Series)` to that column
- provided option to expand all lists

```
def normalize(js, expand_all=False):
    df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(js) if type(js)==str else js)
    # get first column that contains lists
    col = df.applymap(type).astype(str).eq("<class 'list'>").all().idxmax()
    # explode list and expand embedded dictionaries
    df = df.explode(col).reset_index(drop=True)
    df = df.drop(columns=[col]).join(df[col].apply(pd.Series), rsuffix=f".{col}")
    # any lists left?
    if expand_all and df.applymap(type).astype(str).eq("<class 'list'>").any(axis=1).all():
        df = normalize(df.to_dict("records"))
    return df

js = """{ "id": "0001", "type": "donut", "name": "Cake", "ppu": 0.55, "batters": { "batter": [ { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" }, { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }, { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" }, { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" } ] }, "topping": [ { "id": "5001", "type": "None" }, { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" }, { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" } ] }"""

normalize(js, expand_all=True)
```

|  | id | type | name | ppu | id.topping | type.topping | id.batters.batter | type.batters.batter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0001 | donut | Cake | 0.55 | 5001 | None | 1001 | Regular |
| 1 | 0001 | donut | Cake | 0.55 | 5001 | None | 1002 | Chocolate |
| 2 | 0001 | donut | Cake | 0.55 | 5001 | None | 1003 | Blueberry |
| 3 | 0001 | donut | Cake | 0.55 | 5001 | None | 1004 | Devil's Food |
| 4 | 0001 | donut | Cake | 0.55 | 5002 | Glazed | 1001 | Regular |
| 5 | 0001 | donut | Cake | 0.55 | 5002 | Glazed | 1002 | Chocolate |
| 6 | 0001 | donut | Cake | 0.55 | 5002 | Glazed | 1003 | Blueberry |
| 7 | 0001 | donut | Cake | 0.55 | 5002 | Glazed | 1004 | Devil's Food |
| 8 | 0001 | donut | Cake | 0.55 | 5005 | Sugar | 1001 | Regular |
| 9 | 0001 | donut | Cake | 0.55 | 5005 | Sugar | 1002 | Chocolate |
| 10 | 0001 | donut | Cake | 0.55 | 5005 | Sugar | 1003 | Blueberry |
| 11 | 0001 | donut | Cake | 0.55 | 5005 | Sugar | 1004 | Devil's Food |

#### consider each list independent

- copy way this works https://data.page/json/csv
- this is a limited use case,  it does not honor general data modelling principles

```
def n2(js):
    df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(js))
    # columns that contain lists
    cols = [i for i, c in df.applymap(type).astype(str).eq("<class 'list'>").all().iteritems() if c]
    # use list from first row
    return pd.concat(
        [df.drop(columns=cols)]
        + [pd.json_normalize(df.loc[0, c]).pipe(lambda d: d.rename(columns={c2: f"{c}.{c2}" for c2 in d.columns}))
            for c in cols],
        axis=1,
    ).fillna("")
```

Comment: hey @rob thanks for your help!
but in this way it will be static i.e. for each different json i will have to provide different configuration then only it will work. and if you see what i have tried, although it is doing the job but it is exploding it horizontally but i want it to be exploded vertically, there, i just supplied the json and then recursively it did all the things..so by any chance if we can make it dynamic?? reason why i am asking is, i don't know at which level, again it can encounter a list..

Comment: updated answer - it you don't want to name column,  but imply column it can be done using utility function provided. I don't see any generic way to drop unwanted rows and replace nan with empty string

Comment: hey man!! you are genius, let me test it for few more samples..

Comment: {
 "id": "0001",
 "type": "donut",
 "name": "Cake",
 "ppu": 0.55,
 "batters":
  {
   "batter":
    [
     { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
     { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
     { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
     { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
    ]
  },
 "topping":
  [
   { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
   { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
   { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" }
  ]
}

can you try with above json ? it is not giving expected output.

Comment: minor update to answer - need to ensure `join()` generates unique column names.  for sample above there are two embedded lists, you can expand by calling twice: `normalize(normalize(js).to_dict("records"))`

Comment: they are not duplicates - go back to data modelling theory basics,  i.e. Codd's theory.  multiple repeating groups, hence records are a product of all the sub-groups

Comment: yeah @Rob !! i got it .. that is why i deleted that comment immediately!! thanks for your all help.. :) will test it for some more. really a big thank you!

Comment: final update - have further enhanced function to expand all lists,  which will give a product of the lists

Comment: thank you so much @rob it's working fine. just asking if we can avoid displaying those records which gets generated after that product. so as in above instead of showing only 4 rows it is showing 12 rows. sorry for asking this silly question. if you go to below link and test any of the above json, it is not displaying those extra rows. 
https://data.page/json/csv by any chance if that is possible ?

Comment: out of interest I have coded it up and added to answer.  I think it's a very dangerous and limiting approach to data management

Comment: no problem sir!! you already helped a lot here! i will try to figure out if there is any way possible.. thanks once again!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236892/discussion-between-mayank-gupta-and-rob-raymond).

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use pandas to do this but It will repeat the header values for each line like below

---

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fwjq.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLNzK.png)

Comment: thanks @rao-yasir but i want it to explode at each level, so your output is still having dict values.

Comment: @mayankgupta Yeah then would need to write custom parser let me try one out and will post if I'm successful

Comment: @rao-yasir Welcome to SO. Please post your code and output as (formatted) text, not as links to images. Links can be broken, and images cannot be copied/pasted in an editor

Comment: @gimix Sure I will

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.1/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

data = json.loads("""{"menu": {
    "header": "SVG Viewer",
    "items": [
        {"id": "Open"},
        {"id": "OpenNew", "label": "Open New"},
        null,
        {"id": "ZoomIn", "label": "Zoom In"},
        {"id": "ZoomOut", "label": "Zoom Out"},
        {"id": "OriginalView", "label": "Original View"},
        null,
        {"id": "Quality"},
        {"id": "Pause"},
        {"id": "Mute"},
        null,
        {"id": "Find", "label": "Find..."},
        {"id": "FindAgain", "label": "Find Again"},
        {"id": "Copy"},
        {"id": "CopyAgain", "label": "Copy Again"},
        {"id": "CopySVG", "label": "Copy SVG"},
        {"id": "ViewSVG", "label": "View SVG"},
        {"id": "ViewSource", "label": "View Source"},
        {"id": "SaveAs", "label": "Save As"},
        null,
        {"id": "Help"},
        {"id": "About", "label": "About Adobe CVG Viewer..."}
    ]
}}""")

# remove null
data['menu']['items'] = [i for i in data['menu']['items'] if i is not None]

pd.json_normalize(data['menu'], record_path=['items'], meta=['header'], record_prefix='items_')

#   items_id    items_label
# header        
# SVG Viewer    Open    NaN
# SVG Viewer    OpenNew Open New
# SVG Viewer    ZoomIn  Zoom In
# SVG Viewer    ZoomOut Zoom Out
# SVG Viewer    OriginalView    Original View
# SVG Viewer    Quality NaN
# SVG Viewer    Pause   NaN
# SVG Viewer    Mute    NaN
# SVG Viewer    Find    Find...
# SVG Viewer    FindAgain   Find Again
# SVG Viewer    Copy    NaN
# SVG Viewer    CopyAgain   Copy Again
# SVG Viewer    CopySVG Copy SVG
# SVG Viewer    ViewSVG View SVG
# SVG Viewer    ViewSource  View Source
# SVG Viewer    SaveAs  Save As
# SVG Viewer    Help    NaN
# SVG Viewer    About   About Adobe CVG Viewer...
```

Comment: Thanks @Epsi95 and really appreciate your help! but in this way it will be static i.e. for each different json i will have to provide different configuration then only it will work. and if you see what i have tried, although it is doing the job but it is exploding it horizontally but i want it to be exploded vertically, there, i just supplied the json and then recursively it did all the things..